# Chrome dev-tool: Implement your own elements hierarchy view (same chrome, react dev tool)

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I am building a devtool like react-devtool or vue-devtool.

We have a component hierarchy same as HTML DOM.
We would want to represent it graphically like it is done in chrome(or any browser) inspector window elements panel. Looking for a pre-built library or chrome APIs that are available else I would have to build the whole representation manually.

For chrome I have built the panel but I am not sure about existing solutions to represent the DOM object that I have in graphical format.

Example: chrome dev-tool elements panel.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [DOM.getDocument](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM#method-getDocument) will return the entire tree for you.

See [DevTools protocol via Chrome Extension](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#extension).